# Big endian and little endian confusion

Tags: memory, endianness

[endian http://vvcap.net/db/iTMVDXytoaUXJhefNDJy.png](http://vvcap.net/db/iTMVDXytoaUXJhefNDJy.htp)

These two memory spaces store the same data, and I'm trying to write in the counterpart of each one, but I'm confused because, for example, the first given little endian row starts with 11, the lowest number, while the next one starts with 88, the highest. Could anyone please help explain this to me?

Comment: I think the numbers are just there as examples, not as a guide to direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint, that's like looking at (decimal) 32 and 57, in one case 3 > 2, but in the other 5 < 7. They're both okay.

The machine is treating each 4-byte row as a single number. The point of endianness is how are those 4 bytes arranged, in terms of memory address. I don't want to be much more explicit and risk depriving you of the exercise, but I find the diagram on wikipedia to be very helpful visualizing this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I have a better understanding now. Initially I thought the values would be mirrored, but after thinking about it some more I realized that since the indexes are mirrored (e.g. first row Big Endian indexes are 3|2|1|0 and first row Little Endian indexes are 0|1|2|3), then the values of the two arrangements in this case would be identical. Just wanted to confirm with you: is this conclusion accurate, or is my thought process wrong?